# CFArray to NSData to NSImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsdata, nsimage

I've got a plist file with jpeg photo data in it. I need to get that photo out. I can read the plist file into an NSDictionary and can access the object at the key "jpegphoto". The problem is that the object returned is an NSCFArray that I have no idea how to work with. I can print it and I see a nice stream of octets come out, but that's all I know how to do. How do I get this NSCFArray into NSData or a byte array?

The CFArray when passed to NSLog like so

```
NSLog(@"%@", [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"jpegphoto"]);
```

Spits out hundreds of line similar to

```
5ed15ee6 df44b2ff 00899699 0dd23b58 dccdcadc 6c8d04e1 8b3e1940 af76953e 7c0e1b56
```

I know that it is a CFArray b/c I did

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[data_dictionary objectForKey:@"jpegphoto"] class]));
```

And got back

```
NSCFArray
```

Thanks

Comment: NSCFArray == NSArray == CFArrayRef.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of off the top of my head would be this:

```
NSArray * array = [ data_dictionary valueForKey:@"jpegphoto" ] ;
NSMutableData * data = [ NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:array.count * 4 ] ;
uint32_t * dataPtr = [ data mutableBytePtr ] ;
NSUInteger index = 0 ;
for( NSNumber * number in array )
{
    dataPtr[ index++ ] = [ number unsignedLongValue ] ;
}
```

Assuming the array is full of CF/NSNumber instances.
If it's a CFArray of primitive (non-object) values, try something like this:

```
CFArrayRef array = (CFArrayRef)[ data_dictionary valueForKey:@"jpegphoto" ] ;
CFDataRef data = CFDataCreateMutable( kCFAllocatorDefault, CFArrayGetCount( array ) * 4 ) ;
CFArrayGetValues( array, (CFRange){ 0, CFArrayGetCount( array ) }, (void**)CFDataGetMutableBytePtr( data ) ) ;
```

Comment: your data is in 'data' in both cases. (an NS/CFData)